# How to combine two or more formulas into one cell but if one condition is true that result i should get

Tags: excel-formula

In Below Code, If I use **OR** Condition it will work, but I don't know how to use OR condition.

`=IF(AND(K2="Quality Healthcare"),VLOOKUP(L2,Dropdown!E80:F84,2,0)),IF(AND(K2="Sky Lakes Medical Center"),VLOOKUP(L2,Dropdown!E80:F84,2,0))`

Please help on this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AND() function in your formula contains only one element in each case. That does not make sense. If you want to combine the two conditions with a logical OR operator, then try

```
=IF(OR(K2="Tuality Healthcare",K2="Sky Lakes Medical Center"),VLOOKUP(L2,Dropdown!E80:F84,2,0),"K2 has another value")
```

Comment: Thanks alot but I have too many K2 values. Is there any easy way to simply the formula.Because I am getting an error called 'You have entered too many arguments for this function".Could you please help on this. Many thanks.

Comment: Post your exact formula. Maybe you are not closing the brackets correctly. How many different K2 values are there? OR() can handle 255. But with more than a few you want a different technique, anyway.